# Getting a TypError saying that my exported function is not a function with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots, spotify

My goal is to create a discord bot that plays Spotify music, but when I run the function that plays music it gives me the error:

> **TypeError: playSong is not a function**

Here is what is in my api.js:

```
const playSong = (songName) => {
    spotifyApi.searchTracks(songName)
        .then(data => {
            const track = data.body.tracks.items[0];
            const trackId = track.id;
            spotifyApi.play({
                device_id: '',
                uris: [`spotify:track:${trackId}`]
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);

        });
};

module.exports = { playSong };
```

And here is in my play.js:

```
const { playSong } = require('../spotify_api/api.js');

let msg = message.content
        let song = msg.replace('!play ', '');

        //creates the audio player
        if (message.content === `!play ${song}`) {
            //VoiceChannel IDs

            //Audio Player
            const player = createAudioPlayer()
            player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Playing, () => {
                client.message.reply(`Now playing: ${song}`)
                console.log(`Now playing: ${song}`)
            })

            player.on('error', err => {
                console.log(`Error: ${err.message} with resource`)
            })

            //creat and play audio
            player.play(playSong(song)); //This is where I call the function

            //Subscribe the connection to the audio player
            const subscription = connection.subscribe(player)

            if (subscription) {
                //Unsubscribe the subscription
                setTimeout(() => subscription.unsubscribe(), 120000)
            }


        }
```

I have tried to use other methods I know of but it all comes down to the same TypeError. T_T

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace

```
const playSong = () =>
```

with

```
function playSong()
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of

```
module.exports = { playSong };
```

Use

```
module.exports.playSong = playSong;
```

Comment: It still gives me the same error, thanks for the help though.

Comment: maybe you entered wrong directory for api.js file?

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.